# Java for loops slow down game

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, textures

I am having some trouble where I have a huge paint function in java and i run many for loops. The objects that I want to paint are in ArrayList's so I have to use a for loop to draw them all. Is there any way to make this a lot faster? I have already integrated texture culling meaning that anything that is not needed, is not drawn. But the for loop runs for all objects to: 1. evaluate if the object is actually visible and should be drawn 2. draw the object if it is visible.

Thanks in advance and I hope you can help me :D

[edit]
This is how i'd use it:

```
for(int loop = 0; loop < objects.size(); loop++)
{
    g2d.drawImage(objects.get(loop).image, objects.get(loop).x, objects.get(loop).y, null)
}
```

Obviously, i initialise my ArrayList somewhere else:

```
ArrayList<Block> objects = new ArrayList<Block>();
```

Comment: Yes, don't run the loop.  Seriously, is this all the info you are giving?

Comment: How about using threads?

Comment: You should give us an example how you typically use `for`. And you also should make clear if you consider the overhead of the `for` loop itself to expensive or if you are searching a better algorithm overall.

Comment: @A.H. I updated the thing above with how i typically use it

Comment: First, you should make sure that it really is the drawing part that is taking a long time.  Then you could look at multi-threading.  If that still does not work, you would have to change your code such that you do all your drawing in OpenGL (even if it's just 2-dim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the overhead of the `for` loop is *really* the culprit, the you can optimize it a little like this:

```
int numBlocks = objects.size();
for(int loop = 0; loop < numBlocks; loop++)
{
    Block block = objects.get(loop);
    g2d.drawImage(block.image, block.x, block.y, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for slowness is that you are calling the same objects.get(loop) 3 times in the same line.  It is however possible that the JIT optimizes this away.  Somebody who knows the JIT better than I could elaborate.